# C++ and SFML - Transforming by decimal causes artifacts

Tags: c++, decimal, sdl, sfml, game-development

I’m making a game with C++ and SFML. I have delta time in my game by setting it to clock.restart().asSeconds() and then multiplying that by a movement offset. The only issue is that when the final movement value is not an integer (or .0f), it causes rendering artifacts between my sprites. I have a grid of sprites that are all lined up next to each other. When I move by an integer offset, it looks good. However, when moving with a decimal, I can see strange lines between the sprites. Is there any way of fixing this?

note: I don't want to round the deltatime * offset value because when fps is too high, it will be rounded to 0 and the player will not move at all.

delta time code:

```
void Game::run()
{
    init();
    Gui::init();
    Gui::mainMenu();

    sf::Clock deltaClock;

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event loopEvent;
        while (window.pollEvent(loopEvent))
        {
            switch (loopEvent.type)
            {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                saveGame();
                window.close();
                break;
            case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
                if (loopEvent.key.code == Gui::keybinds[Action::EXIT_MENU] && Player::hasSpawned)
                {
                    Gui::inMenu = false;
                    Gui::currentGameState = GameState::SETTINGS;
                }
            }
        }

        deltaTime = deltaClock.restart().asSeconds();
        update();

        window.setView(camera);
        window.clear(sf::Color::White);

        draw();
        window.display();

        Gui::checkGameState();
    }
}

const float Game::MAKE_DELTA(const float OFFSET)
{
    return OFFSET * deltaTime;
}
```

Moving with integer offset (or when I round the return value of MAKE_DELTA()):

[image]

Moving with decimal offset (unrounded return value from MAKE_DELTA()):

[image]

Comment: *Is there any way of fixing this?* -- That question has a yes or no answer.  Maybe add some detail, like the code itself?

Comment: ok I added more information

Comment: What does "strange lines" between sprites mean? What I can see so far is that you are rendering at max fps. The functions update() and draw() are inside a while loop.

Comment: The image attached shows distinct lines between tiles